# Modificar texto en QLineEdit cuando se modifique el valor de una variable/atributo de instancia

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy tratando de mandar el valor de un `QLineEdit` de un módulo a otro en otro módulo al presionar un botón, pero no funciona (simplemente no cambia el texto en el segundo `QLineEdit`).

Este es mi código:

**Modulo1**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from main2 import Main2

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("main1.ui",self)


        self.otra = Main2()
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.dato)

    def dato(self):
        self.otra.variable = self.lineEdit_0.text()
        self.otra.show()



app= QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Main2**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic


class Main2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("main2.ui",self)

        self.variable = None
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.variable)




#app= QApplication([])
#m = Main()
#m.show()
#app.exec_()
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner los ficheros `.ui` en algún sitio donde poder descargarlos? Eso haría más sencillo replicar el problema

Comment: Yo no veo que estés pasando ninguna variable al otro qlineedit. Pero estoy con @abulafia, si no pones un código completo y verificable que podamos probar, no podemos darte mucha más ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, realmente no quieres "mandar valor a una variable de otro módulo", lo que quieres es modificar un atributo de instancia de un objeto cuya clase está definida en otro módulo. Realmente no importa dónde esté definida la clase, lo importante es el objeto `otra` que instancias a partir de ella.

El problema es que asignas como texto del `QLineEdit` el valor de variable en solo en el `__init__`, esto hace que cuando instancias la clase con `self.otra = Main2()` durante la inicializan de la misma el texto del `QlineEdit` pase a ser el valor de `self.variable` en este instante, pero esto no crea ningún vínculo entre ambas, si después se modifica `self.variable` el texto del `QlineEdit` no va a cambiar.

Podrías simplemente modificar el texto del `QLineEdit` de `otra` directamente:

```
self.otra.lineEdit.setText(self.lineEdit_0.text())
```

Pero si quieres usar un atributo de instancia, la solución es usar una `property` que te permita modificar el `QLineEdit` cuando se asigne un nuevo valor a la misma en el "setter":

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Main2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 84, 260, 32))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self._variable = None  # Variable "privada", de uso interno.

    @property
    def variable(self):
        return self._variable

    @variable.setter
    def variable(self, text):
        self._variable = text
        self.lineEdit.setText(text)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.boton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, text="Aceptar")
        self.boton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 280, 88, 34))
        self.lineEdit_0 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 240, 411, 32))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.otra = Main2()
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.dato)

    def dato(self):
        self.otra.variable = self.lineEdit_0.text()
        self.otra.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Podrías incluso crear tu propia señal y emitirla cuando el atributo sea modificado, señal que puedes conectar a los `slots` que quieras posteriormente:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Main2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    variable_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 84, 260, 32))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self._variable = None  
        self.variable_changed.connect(self.on_changed)

    @property
    def variable(self):
        return self._variable

    @variable.setter
    def variable(self, text):
        self._variable = text
        self.variable_changed.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_changed(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self._variable)
```

No obstante, la asociación no es recíproca, es decir, si se reasigna un valor al atributo el contenido del `QlineEdit` cambia, pero si se modifica el `QLineEdit` el atributo no se modifica. si quieres que esto pase, deberás conectar la señal [`textChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged) a un slot que se encargue de modificar adecuadamente el atributo,  una posibilidad es:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Main2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 84, 260, 32))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self._variable = None  # Variable "privada", de uso interno.
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self._lineEdit_changed)

    @property
    def variable(self):
        return self._variable

    @variable.setter
    def variable(self, text):
        self.lineEdit.setText(text)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def _lineEdit_changed(self):
        self._variable = self.lineEdit.text()
```

---

`Main2` está definida en el mismo módulo para facilitar la reproducción pero como se comentó  es irrelevante que esté declarada en otro módulo y la importes. No debes confundir el concepto de módulo con los conceptos de clase e instancia de clase/objeto pertenecientes al paradigma de la programación orientada a objetos. Un módulo a grandes rasgos es solo un archivo que permite almacenar código y estructurar nuestra aplicación. En un módulo podemos definir múltiples funciones, clases, variables, etc y podemos ejecutarlo directamente como script o importarlo en otro módulo para reutilizar el código definido en él.